# How to decrypt a RSA plaintext given a public exponent e and a RSA modulus n

Tags: encryption, rsa, decryption

I am doing a RSA cryptography task where I need to decrypt a ciphertext but I am only given the ciphertext ,c, a public exponent, e, and a RSA modulus, n, which has two prime factors p and q such that |p − q| < 10000.

I am unsure of how to do this but I am given the hint of using a low exponent attack (although the exponent is the usual 65537) and a binary search somewhere.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the distance between $p$ and $q$ is too short you can perform Fermat's Attack

in  [this link](https://asecuritysite.com/rsa/rsa_01) you'll get full explanation

Comment: The question's _"I am given the hint of using a low exponent attack (although the exponent is the usual 65537) and a binary search somewhere"_ is at odds with this answer. Strictly speaking, _"$n$ has two prime factors $p$ and $q$ such that $|p−q|<10000$"_ does not imply that Fermat factorization will succeed. It's still entirely possible that $n$ has three prime factors, as allowed by [PKCS#1](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr). With the primes large enough and the third chosen independently of $p$ and $q$, no known method to factorize $n$ from the stated givens would succeed.